# Mapping through array of objects after filtering and displaying dynamic common property

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have an array of objects:

```
  const students = [
    { name: 'Tom', class: "Blue" },
    { name: 'Pom', class: "Blue" },
    { name: 'Max', class: "Red" },
    { name: 'Alex', class: "Red" },
    { name: 'John', class: "Yellow" }
  ];
```

And I would like to group the return values by the class property, so I can achieve something similar to this in HTML:

```
Class Blue: Tom, Pom
Class Red: Max, Alex
Class Yellow: John
```

*note: the class property should be displayed once as HTML mark-up which is the reason I don't think [this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects) at all..*

**How should I go about it?** I can user `filter()` (like below) but this is rather silly.

```
const classRed = students.filter(student => student.class === "Red);
const classBlue = students.filter(student => student.class === "Blue);
...
```

I [started this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vcw2emy6/37/), but not sure how to deal with this object to display how I want it.

Comment: Made some changes to your fiddle snippet: https://jsfiddle.net/8o2dxhjk/4/

Comment: Thanks @smac89, that's what I am trying to avoid though, 3+ separate loops, as the class property would be dynamic so I won't know it or how many will I get in my object.